# how to get the response JSON in swift

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I got a response from my Alamofire post request. I want to get the Status code from the response.
Here in the code:

```
case .success(let upload, _, _):
    upload.responseJSON { response in
        print(response.result.value!)
    }
```

Here is the response looks like:

[image: Response image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `value` property of the response's result is a dictionary. You can extract status like this:

```
let json = response.result.value as? [String: Any]
if let status = json?["status"] as? Int {
    print(status)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Use responseDecodable in Alamofire 5 with Codable Structure

Replace responseJSON with responseDecodable.

```swift
.responseDecodable { (response: AFDataResponse<ProfileModel>) in
        switch response.result {
        case .success(let profileModel):
            switch profileModel.status {
            case 200:
                print("success")
            case 101:
                print("sessionExpire")
            default:
                print("default")
            }
        case .failure(let error):
            print("failure")
        }
    }
```

### ProfileModel

```swift
struct ProfileModel: Codable {
    let status: Int
    let type: String
    let data: ProfileDataModel
}

struct ProfileDataModel: Codable {
    let ImagePath: String
    let ThumbImagePath: String
}
```